# what is the meaning of "Best viewed at 1024 X 768"?

Tags: language-agnostic

I am in the process of designing web-app, and would like to know what the following statement means/claims to be "Best viewed at 1024 x 768" ?

Does it mean if my monitor is set to 1024 * 768 and I browse that site which claims to support this resolution , I will not get horizontal/vertical scroll bars or does it mean something else.What care should one take during the design to make sure it adheres to this resolution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that the site is best viewed with a 1024x768 screen resolution.

Don't use it though. Different people have different screen sizes and it is best to try let your design flow to match it.

Besides, 1024x768 is the minimum screen size you should be designing for today.

Comment: Does this mean I should never set the width/height explicitly on the container panels on which the screen elements are placed, so that they adapt to any screen resolution ?.

Comment: It's up to you, but it is preferred that you don't. See: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/

Answer (score 2):

I think for the most part it means "minimum resolution the monitor should be set to". At least thats what i've always meant when i would put that in :).

Answer (score 0):

I means the minimum monitor resolution setup. But i can give you a good sugestion try to build your app as free as you can I usualy use a lot of zoom in web and some apps don't like it.